# Why is my javascript not executed within this Razor code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, raphael

I have some working Raphael-js code from this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/ and I'm trying to include the working code in to an MVC3 Razor view.  The javascript isn't getting executed.  I can't seem to find the error or a good resorce which explains how to include javascript within Razor.
Here is my .cshtml where I expect the Rapheael drawing to be rendered at the canvas_container div.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">
        http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>

<div id="canvas_container">
</div>

@section JavaScript
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/raphael.js")" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
            var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 80);
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
                var multiplier = i * 5;
                paper.circle(250 + (2 * multiplier), 100 + multiplier, 50 - multiplier)
            }
            var rectangle = paper.rect(200, 200, 250, 100);
            var ellipse = paper.ellipse(200, 400, 100, 50);
        }
    </script>
}
```

And here is the rendered view where the javascript is not executed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>MVC Movie App</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                    [ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
                <h2>Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!</h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">
            http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>

    <div id="canvas_container">
    </div>
        </section>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/raphael.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
                var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 80);
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
                    var multiplier = i * 5;
                    paper.circle(250 + (2 * multiplier), 100 + multiplier, 50 - multiplier)
                }
                var rectangle = paper.rect(200, 200, 250, 100);
                var ellipse = paper.ellipse(200, 400, 100, 50);
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not working because your javascript follows a self-closed `script` tag, which is [invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work).

You need to change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/raphael.js" />
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/raphael.js"></script>
```

Comment: That same reasoning fixed my problem as well. Thanks!